# When can limits be moved to coefficients in power series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the following "proof" that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\exp x$ (with the right-hand side defined as $\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^k}{k!}$, which is everywhere convergent by the ratio test):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\stackrel{1}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(n)_k}{k!n^k}x^k\stackrel{2}{=}\sum_{k\ge0}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n)_k}{k!n^k}\right)x^k\stackrel{3}{=}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$Here $\stackrel{1}{=}$ uses the binomial theorem for $n\in\Bbb N$ (we're seeking the limit of a sequence), and $\stackrel{3}{=}$ just requires verifying $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n)_k}{n^k}=1$ for any $k\ge0$, which is easy enough. This question is about $\stackrel{2}{=}$, where we use the "identity" $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_kc_k(n)x^k=\sum_k\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}c_k(n)\right)x^k.$$What condition is sufficient for this identity?

Here are my thoughts. If both sides exist and are finite, their difference is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_kd_k(n)x^k,\,d_k(n):=c_k(n)-\lim_{m\to\infty}c_k(m).$$This reduces the problem to that of finding a condition, in addition to $\lim_{m\to\infty}d_k(m)=0$, that suffices to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_kd_k(n)x^k=0$. Fix $\epsilon>0,\,N\in\Bbb N$ so that$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\left(n\ge N\implies|d_k(n)|<\epsilon\implies\left|\sum_kd_k(n)x^k\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{1-x}\right),$$provided $|x|<1$. But it's unclear when the case $|x|\ge1$ also works.

With the choice $c_k(n):=\frac{(n)_k}{k!n^k}$, $d_k(n)\sim-\frac{k^2}{k!2n}$ for $n\gg k^2$, which is fine because the decline with increasing $k$ is fast enough for arbitrary $x$, while the $\frac1n$ dependence gives an $n\to\infty$ limit of $0$. But this is a condition on $d_k(n)$, not $c_k(n)$; I'm wondering, with an eye to more general problems than this one, if there's a suitable condition on the latter.

Comment: @cmk That's a good tag addition. I'd welcome complex-analytic answers too, but I imagine the results may be similar.

Comment: Have you come across Dominated Convergence Theorem and Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It looks like we need to use the latter viz. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_2) with $a_{j,\,k}:=c_k(j)x^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You can apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem applied to the discrete measure:

Let $(u_{n,i})_{(n,i) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N}$ be a double sequence of complex numbers. Suppose that $u_{n,i} \to v_i$ for all $i$ as $n \to \infty$, and that $\vert u_{n,i} \vert \le w_i$ for all $n$ with $\sum \vert w_i \vert < \infty$. Then for all $n$ the series $\sum_i u_{n,i}$ is absolutely convergent and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}u_{n,i}=\sum_i v_i$.